# Apache POI dependencies?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I can't find what is the problem with my project. I'm trying to create a header for a word document I'm making but when I try these lines of code:

```
    XWPFHeader header = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy().getFirstPageHeader();
    XWPFRun headRun = header.getParagraphArray(1).createRun();
    headRun.setText("SOME TEXT");
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error(55,20): XmlString not found  in interface org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr in class org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy in class ****.***.*****.MyDocument
Error(55,20): StringEnumAbstractBase not found  in class org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHdrFtr.Enum in class org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy in class ****.***.*****.MyDocument
```

I have tried to search for the error message but I find nothing, can someone please give me some help? I would appreciate specially if someone can tell me an effective way to address these problems, googling the error message has always worked for me, but not this time. I don't know how to find a jar (as it seems to be what is missing) by what classes are in it.

Thanks.

PS. This is the first time I try to create a document, so the code may just be completely wrong.

Comment: Are you using Maven or are you deploying dependencies manually?

Comment: @Behnil Doing it manually. I don't know maven, I'll take a look. I'm using jDeveloper.

Comment: Do you maybe have an old or broken copy of XMLBeans? And do you have all the dependencies listed on the [POI Components and Dependency page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache POI components](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) and this [FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025). You are definitely missing something.